# how to I select only a specific column from a Dataset after sorting it

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following table:

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States       Romania             15
United States       Croatia             1
United States       Ireland             344
Egypt               United States       15
```

The table is represented as a Dataset.

```
scala> dataDS
res187: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[FlightData] = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]
```

I want to sort the table based on `count` column and want to see only count column. I have done it but I am doing it in 2 steps

1- I first sort to get sorted DS - `dataDS.sort(col("count").desc)`
2- then select on that DS- `(dataDS.sort(col("count").desc)).select(col("count")).show();`

The above feels like am embedded sql query to me. In `sql` however, I can do the same query without using an embedded query
`select * from flight_data_2015 ORDER BY count ASC`

Is there a better way for me to both sort and select without creating a new `Dataset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong

```
(dataDS.sort(col("count").desc)).select(col("count")).show();
```

It is the right thing to do and has no negative performance implications, other than intrinsic problems of sorting as such.

Use it freely and don't worry about it anymore.